# JAX-RS Custom @Provider for a subset of the type

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have an API with the following return type:

```
class Example {
  private Complex1 complex1;
  private Complex2 complex2;
}
```

Complex1 and Complex2:

```
class Complex1 {
  private String test1;
  private String test2;
}

class Complex2 {
  private String test3;
  private String test4;
}
```

Now I would like to make use of standard serialization for Complex1 but add custom serialization for Complex2.

I tried to add a Provider for Complex2. But JAX-RS seems to be not aware of it since it is not the actual return type. If I add a Provider for Example JAX-RS makes use of my custom Provider. But having a custom Provider for Example has the drawback that I have to add logic for Complex1 too although standard serialization would be OK for Complex1.

In this example it would be OK, to do serialization for Complex1 too, but in my scenario Complex1 is huge and would like to avoid implementing serialization logic for Complex1.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: What format is the data and what framework are you using for serialization?

Comment: The data format I have is Java object and I want to have JSON. I am using Jackson for serialization. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it won't work like that. A single JSON provider is used for the entire serialization. It already knows how to serialize the entire object. There is just no way for Jackson to know that a different provider is needed *mid-serialization* (especially because Jackson doesn't even have any knowledge of providers, that is a JAX-RS concept).

At the Jackson level though, we can tell Jackson how to serialize with the use `JsonSerializer`s. You can have a look at [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) for writing custom serializers. Once you have the serilizer, then you can annotate `Complex2` class with the custom serializer

```
@JsonSerialize(using = Complex2Serializer.class)
public class Complex2 {}
```